# Nopcommerce: Nop.Admin New Menu item always shows nopResource text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have created new controller, view and added this newly created controller into sitemap.config as mentioned below,

```
<siteMapNode title="Product Registration" nopResource="Admin.ContentManagement.ProductRegistration.ProductRegistration"  controller="ProductRegistration" action="Index"/>
```

but every time when i am getting

****Admin.ContentManagement.ProductRegistration.ProductRegistration****

as menu item. whereas, i am want ****Product Registration**** as menu item text.

any reason?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have solved this, you need to add record into configuration--> language

in my case, resource is.
*Admin.ContentManagement.ProductRegistration.ProductRegistration*

Hope it will help someone.